# how to get value of parameter and pass it to a stored procedure?

Tags: reporting-services

I have to build a stored procedure and pass it a parameter from the report and  to execute the stored procedure which its parameters are chosen in report ssrs , It is a possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you should be able to set the dataset command type to 'StoredProcedure' and set the parameter to your report parameters.  Please let me know if more details are needed.

[image]

[image]